# Fill in database connection info given service name

Tags: oracle, nextep

I'm using neXtep database version software. It allows me to track both schema and data changes between Oracle "instances". To do this, it asks for connection information, but the connection information I have gives me an ORA-12505 error.

This is a screenshot of the connection dialog as I filled it out.
https://paste.pics/555XJ

The JDBC URL is

```
jdbc:oracle:oci:@(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=22.33.44.55)(PORT=1541))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MY_SERVICE_NAME)))
```

The software is NeXtep Designer
Version: 3.6.1.v20100908-1100-4507w31211A2403131
Build id: 201009132020

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

For what it's worth, I do not have Oracle installed locally, so I never set up that tnsnames.ora file, nor do I know if I need it.

I didn't see a way to just paste the JDBC URL in, but hope that it can be reconstructed based on the fields in the dialog.

I'm expecting the result to be a successful connection. When I test the connection, I get "Status: Failed! Listener refued the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor"

Comment: If you don't have an Oracle client (and thus tnsnames.ora) you have to use the thin driver. Try: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//22.33.44.55:1541/MY_SERVICE_NAME` or - depending on the Oracle version and configuration - use the SID instead of the service name

Comment: The program does not allow me to specify a driver, and I'm not sure what it's currently using.  Would it be easier or possible to download a free Oracle client to solve this?

Comment: You don't specify a "driver", you just use a different JDBC URL (which tells the existing JDBC driver to use a different protocol implementation). If you can't specify the URL, then how did you specify the one in your question? Did you try to specify a SID instead of a service name?

Comment: I only had the dialog given to me. The JDBC URL above is from the project source code. Most programs that interact with a database provide a place to just give it a JDBC URL and be done with it, but not this one.

Comment: Again: did you try a SID instead of a service name?

Comment: No, I only used the info from the JDBC above.  I do not know what the SID is.